# In HTML I need to create a submit button that performs an onclick event, a JS function to calculate distance using the distance formula

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home Lab 4</title>
 <head>

 </head>
 <body>

 <table border="4px" bordercolor="navy" bgcolor="white" cellpadding="4px">

 <tr>
 <td>X-coordinate 1:</td> 
 <td><input type="text" id="x1"></td>
 <td>X-coordinate 2:</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="x1"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Y-coordinate 1:</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="x1"></td>
 <td>Y-coordinate 2:</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="x1"></td>

 </center>
 </table>  

<script type="text/javascript">
function distance()
{
distance=sqrt( (x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y2)^2 )

var a = [564,426];
var b = [56,784];

var xN = Math.pow( b[0] - a[0], 2 );
var yN = Math.pow( b[1] - a[1], 2 );

var distance = Math.sqrt(xN + yN);


alert(distance);
}

</script>

<br>
 <input type="button" onclick="distance()" value="distance">





</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, but I cannot get the values to calculate. I also need help with an alert that pops up to display the calculated value. I have tried numerous times change different things and everything stays the same. Any help would be excellent.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ScottHunter It's CS homework

Comment: Why are you assigning to the name of your function from within your function, and THEN declaring it as a variable?

Comment: Look in your browser's JavaScript console for errors.

Comment: You forgot to close the 2nd `<tr>` of your table

Comment: You also have a `</center>` with no opening tag

Comment: Also, why are you using the bitwise XOR operator in the sqrt() method?

Comment: First, X and Y inputs have same ID. And where do you define x2, x1, y2 variables?

Comment: And also, is a good practice to finish your code lines with a semicolon: `distance=sqrt( (x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y2)^2 )`

Comment: + how do you think to get input values?)))) maybe x1 = document.getElementById("x1").value;

Comment: Okay, I have fixed all suggestions, and still have no luck. I do keep getting a message that tells me "UncaughtReferenceError:x2 not defined" and it is saying this problem is here "distance=sqrt( (x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y2)^2 )"

Comment: And the interpreter is right. You haven't defined `x2`, as the same for `x1`, `y1` and `y2`

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I have defined everything now and the distance formula is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that may be you want to write something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home Lab 4</title>
</head>
 <body>

 <table border="4px" bordercolor="navy" bgcolor="white" cellpadding="4px">

 <tr>
 <td>X-coordinate 1:</td> 
 <td><input type="text" id="x1"/></td>
 <td>X-coordinate 2:</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="x2"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Y-coordinate 1:</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="y1"/></td>
 <td>Y-coordinate 2:</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="y2"/></td>
 </tr>
 </table>  

<script type="text/javascript">
function distance()
{
    var x1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("x1").value);
    var x2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("x2").value);
    var y1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("y1").value);
    var y2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("y2").value);
    var distance = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2) );

    var a = [564,426];
    var b = [56,784];

    var xN = Math.pow( b[0] - a[0], 2 );
    var yN = Math.pow( b[1] - a[1], 2 );

    distance = Math.sqrt(xN + yN);

    alert(distance);
}

</script>

<br/>
 <input type="button" onclick="distance()" value="distance" />

</body>
</html>
```

But, anyway your code doesn't make much sense, because you are calculating `distance` and overriding its value in the line before the `alert`...

Comment: Yes, I noticed that and removed it. Also, how would I make the in answer into a block answer instead of an alert message?

Comment: You have to define a container in your HTML like, for example `<p id="result"></p>` and then replace the `alert` for `document.getElementById("result").value = distance;`